# what stops React component from re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’m new to react and I have a question. I have two components, parent component - Goals and child - EditGoal. Goals component renders all goals, end EditGoal component edits the name of the goal. After child component is done with modification it saves data in the database, and via props I execute a function in the parent component. That function sets the state.  That should cause a parent component to re-render. But for some reason parent component doesn't re-render.  I can't figure out why. The reason I want to re-render parent component so I can get a list of goals with updates, that just has been made by a child. Any ideas why parent component doesn't re-render? or how I can go around it? I would really appreciate any advise!

Goals component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Goal from './Goal';
import EditGoal from './EditGoal';

import moment from 'moment';

class Goals extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      goals: [],
      editingGoalId: 0,
      update: 'false'
    };
    this.getGoals = this.getGoals.bind(this);
    this.populateGoals = this.populateGoals.bind(this);
    this.deleteGoal = this.deleteGoal.bind(this);
    this.editGoal = this.editGoal.bind(this);
    this.updateGoals = this.updateGoals.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getGoals();
  }



  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
console.log('will updated worked!')
  }

  getGoals() {
    $.ajax({
      url: `/api/v1/goals.json`,
      method: 'GET',
      success: this.populateGoals
    });
  }

  populateGoals(data) {
    this.setState({ goals: data.goals });
  }

  deleteGoal(goal) {
    $.ajax({
      url: `/api/v1/goals/${goal.id}`,
      method: 'DELETE'
    })
    .done((data) => {
      this.getGoals();
      console.log('Goal deleted!');

    })
    .fail((response) => {
      console.log.error('There was a problem deleting that goal.');
    });
  }

  editGoal(goal) {
    this.setState({ editingGoalId: goal.id })
  }

  updateGoals(name) {
  let goals = this.state.goals;

  goals = goals.map((currentGoal) =>{
    if(currentGoal.id == this.state.editingGoalId) {
      currentGoal.name = name;
    }
    return currentGoal;
  });

  this.setState({ goals: goals});

  console.log(this.state.goals);
  }

  render() {

    let goals = this.state.goals.map(goal => {
      if(this.state.editingGoalId === goal.id) {
        return(
          <EditGoal key={goal.id}
                    name={goal.name}
                    description={goal.description}
                    dueTime={moment(goal.due_time).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a")}
                    goal={goal}
                    update={this.updateGoals}
           />
          );
       } else {
         return(
          <Goal key={goal.id}
                name={goal.name}
                description={goal.description}
                startDate={moment(goal.created_at).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a")}
                dueTime={moment(goal.due_time).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a")}
                deadline={goal.due_time}
                goal={goal}
                onDelete={this.deleteGoal}
                onEdit={this.editGoal}
          />
          );
        }
    });
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Goals</h1>
      <div>
        {goals}
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Goals;
```

Edit Goal component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Goal from './Goal';

class EditGoal extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      updateGoalErrors: [],
      name: '',
      id: '',
      updatedDescription: '',
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.getNameValue = this.getNameValue.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getNameValue();
  }

  getNameValue(name) {
    this.setState({name: this.props.name});
    this.setState({id: this.props.goal.id});
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({name: event.target.value })
  }

  handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: `/api/v1/goals/${this.state.id}`,
      method: 'PUT',
      dataType:'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify({ name: this.state.name })
    })
    .done((data) => {
      if (data.errors) {
        this.setState({ updateGoalErrors: data.errors });
      } else {
        console.log("Goal updated in database")
        this.props.update(this.state.name);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <textarea value={this.state.name}
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default EditGoal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I can see that you had written ajax call in `componentDidMount` and it will call on first life cycle of component, after that editing goal you had just updated the state `update` to true, but not the list of goals.

You can debug it, after setState on `update` components was re-rendered but, you had not updated the list of goals after updating it to the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added function that updates the list of goals (adds a new name of the goal) to the state, but it didn't make a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

So updating a list of goals in the state like Dipti Tiwari said did help. Thanks for that! Also I had to set editingGoalId to 0, other wise it would render child component.

```
updateGoals(name) {
 let goals = this.state.goals;

  goals = goals.map((currentGoal) =>{
    if(currentGoal.id == this.state.editingGoalId) {
      currentGoal.name = name;
    }
    return currentGoal;
  });

  this.setState({ goals: goals});
  this.setState({editingGoalId: 0 })

  console.log(this.state.goals);
  }
```

It's been a while since I worked on this code so I totally forgot about that if statement that I had there.